# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext' while attempting to activate an api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr, windows-authentication

I'm developing a web application with ASP.NET Core (MVC) that will display some information to a group of users. They will be authenticated using Windows Athentication. I recently started using SignalR because I want them to receive push notifications based on certain actions that are triggered from another program that is written in Python. That Python program send HTTP post requests to an API controller within the web app. However I want those notifications to be sent to specific users.

Here's my post method in the api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Notice notice)
    {
        //_pushHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", notice.Title, notice.Body);
        _pushHub.Clients.User(_nuidProvider.GetUserId(_connection)).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", notice.Title, notice.Body);
    }
```

It receives an object of class Notice which has two fields: Title and Body.

Then I send those values by using the method SendAsync(). When I execute it for all clients, it gets sent successfully. However, since I need it to be sent to specific users, I tried following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I created this class as suggested:

```
namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added this to the StartUp at ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
        services.AddSignalR();
```

And lastly, I modified the JS file to include the sentence: options.UseDefaultCredentials = true; as suggested in the instructions:

```
const conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/pushHub', options => {
    options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
}).build();

conn.on('ReceiveMessage', (title, body) => {
    const t = title.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    const b = body.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    const msg = date + ' ' + t + ' ' + b;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('msgsList').appendChild(li);

    Push.create(title, {
        body: body,
        timeout: 9000
    });
});

conn.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

The complete api controller looks like this, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers.api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NoticesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<PushHub> _pushHub;
        private readonly IUserIdProvider _nuidProvider;
        private readonly HubConnectionContext _connection;

        public NoticesController(IHubContext<PushHub> pushHub, IUserIdProvider nuidProvider, HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            _pushHub = pushHub;
            _nuidProvider = nuidProvider;
            _connection = connection;
        }

        // POST api/<NoticesController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Notice notice)
        {
            //_pushHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", notice.Title, notice.Body);
            _pushHub.Clients.User(_nuidProvider.GetUserId(_connection)).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", notice.Title, notice.Body);
        }

    }
}
```

I think I'm not passing a proper connection object to the GetUserId method.

Any advice will be completely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error is because you are trying to inject `HubConnectionContext` into the controller. Why are trying to inject `HubConnectionContext` into the controller?

Comment: Hello @Nkosi, I injected it because I wanted to use the _connection object, since it's required by the public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection) method ...

Comment: And how did you register `HubConnectionContext` with the DI container?

Comment: @Nkosi I didn't registered it. To be honest I don't know how to do that. Where should I do it?